# Expected value of $X^TY$ in matrix form

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, matrices, statistics

I want to compute $E(\mathbf{X}^T\mathbf{Y})$, where:

$$\mathbf{X} \sim N_d(\mathbf{\mu}, 4\mathbf{I}_d)$$
$$\mathbf{Y} \sim N_d(\mathbf{\mu}, 4\mathbf{I}_d)$$

Independence would seem to imply that this is the same as $E(\mathbf{X}^T)E(\mathbf{Y})$, which would be $||\mu||^2$.

Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\mu$ is a vector.

$$E(X^T)E(Y)=\sum_{i=1}^d \mu_i^2=\mu^T\mu=\|\mu\|^2$$

Comment: There was an issue with bolding of my notation not showing up, fixed - it looks like we have the same answer.